# iOS Google Tag Manager integration - Can not retrieve container from network. Response: 404

Tags: ios, swift, google-tag-manager

I follow documentation about adding Google Tag Manager into project https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5/. I added container folder to my project's target but I am still getting some warnings from GTM to log and it is not possible to track events to Firebase.

GoogleTagManager warning: Can not retrieve container from network. Response: 404
GoogleTagManager warning: Event emitted before runtime was initialized.

What is the proper way to initialize Tag Manager? I use my "containerName" + .json as name of the container file and add them to folder "container".

GTM iOS SDK 7.1.1

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: Hello. Yes, When you download container, his name looks like "GTM-id_v1.json".
I just deleted "_v1" and its solve my problem

Answer (score 3):

Referring to this [link](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/tag-manager/NzTs5Rt451c), the name of the file should be `GTM-XXXXX.json`. When its downloaded, it could be something like `GTM-KZ4ZT31_xxxxxx.json` so you just need to get rid of everything after the `id`, for example this `GTM-KZ4ZT31_xxxxxx` will become `GTM-KZ4ZT31.json`.

Also, double check to use the latest `container` file generated from the `TagManager`

Comment: How can we verify that our container and GTM has been set up properly ? I don't see any logs related to GTM in the Xcode console.